# Excel Sum Range Match Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table in excel:

```
__|______A_______|_________B___________|____C____|                        
1 |Client        | Description         | Amount  |
2 |Client One    | Water Services      | 50      |
3 |Client One    | Installation Fees   | 120     |
4 |Client One    | Telephone Services  | 130     |
5 |Client Two    | Food Services       | 20      |
6 |Client Two    | Pump Installation   | 40      |
7 |Client Two    | Door Installation   | 100     |
8 |Client Three  | Telephone Services  | 98      |
9 |Client Three  | Gas Services        | 34      |
10|Client Three  | Installation Fees   | 46      |
```

I need a formula to calculate the total amount of services for each client and total amount of installation for each client in a second worksheet. For example it should check if the description contains the text "services" in the column B then return the total amount for the client as follows:

```
__|____A________|______B_________|______C_______|
1 |Client       | Description   | Total Amount |
2 |Client One   | Services      | 180          |
3 |Client One   | Installation  | 120          |
4 |Client Two   | Services      | 20           |
5 |Client Two   | Installation  | 140          |
6 |Client Three | Services      | 132          |
7 |Client Three | Installation  | 46           |
```

I have tried the following formula, but I was able to only return the first value for the client and the description (Column B) in sheet 1 has to contain the exact text, that is either "Services" or "Installation":

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C2:C10,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet1!A2:A10&Sheet1!B2:B10,0))
```

1. I need to be able to get the total value instead of the first value.
2. I also needs to search if the the description contain the "Services" or "Installation" then return the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$10=A13)*(IFERROR(FIND(B13,$B$2:$B$10),0)>0)*$C$2:$C$10)
```

This is an *array* formula so to enter the formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I support the solution by CallumDA, as I'm personally a fan of array formulas. However, since the nature of OP's questions suggests somewhat limited Excel-experience, I think Array formulas might be aiming a bit high.

A, in my opinion, simpler alternative is to use *SUMIFS*-formula, e.g.

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10;$A$2:$A$10;"Client One";$B$2:$B$10;"*Service*")
```

Just replace the "Client One" with the range of the other table where you have the clients listed, and I believe you should be good to go. Also, note that the asterix on either side of *Service* function as wildcards so that you get both "Water Service", "Service Truck" and other combinations...

Comment: Very nice suggestion. Why not replace "*Service*" with `"*"&B13&"*"` (e.g. where `B13` has the value "Service" in) as well to remove all need for hardcoding

Comment: Again, fully support your suggestion there CallumDA! Nice addition indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b). You could do something like this to get all of your Client One entries

```
=SUMIF(A2:A10,"Client One",C2:C10)
```

And to get all of your Client One and Services you could do something like this with [ISNUMBER(SEARCH)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-insensitive-7bb505c7-2815-4a7a-9544-57a5f0dcd551) and [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e)

First add an extra column for "Is a Service" with this formula

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Service",B1))
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Service",B2))
...
```

This will return true/false and then do SUMIFS like this

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A10,C2:C10,"Client One",D2:D10,"TRUE")
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the issue that "Installation" covers many different fields like "Pump Installation", "Door Installation",.. etc.

Comment: @CallumDA It would need an intermediate step to group all your installation and services but the update avoids that extra step.